# Post Multiple dropdown values from form to table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, drop-down-menu

Currently I am creating a form (70+ questions) but I am stuck on one part.
I would like to get people to fill in the opening hours for every day of the week.

This will consist of the day of the week followed by 4 dropdowns, 
from : to (afternoon break) from : to

That part of the form looks like this:
http://dgoods.eu/php/form.jpg

How can I get these values into the mysql table? Also please keep in mind that I will have to be able to extract the values from the table and work with them later on.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to retrieve the data from the form, and add it to a MySQL table using and `INSERT` statement with the values. You can then get the values from the table using `SELECT` statements.

EDIT:
I don't know much php, but it would be something like:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tablename (morning_time, evening_time)
           VALUES ('$_POST[combobox1]','$_POST[combobox2]')";
mysql_real_query($sql,$con)
```

Also you can use $_GET instead of  $_POST

You can also take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).

Comment: I do know how to get values from a form into mysql tables. I just wonder how to do it in this specific case with multiple dropdowns. Do I use 1 table or do I have to use multiple tables?

How would you retrieve all these values from the different dropdowns.

Comment: You can use a single table. You would use your getcombobox value function to retrieve the values, store it in an array, and use the mysql_real_query() api to send an insert query. It will be easier to give an example if you tell me which language(s) you are using to program.

Comment: Oh my... forgot to say I am making this in php.

Comment: So for my 4 values a day (from - till / from - till) I would have to create 4*7(days of week) 28 columns to store the whole thing? There must be a better way no? Basicly something like monday(7:8,2:7) thueday(7:8,2:7) and so on should be posted into the mysql coumn. This would mean opened on monday from 7 till 8 and from 2 till 7 on Thuesday open from 7 till 8 and from 2 till 7

Comment: @logistef That is possible, though it would not be normalized. Also, if you have to manipulate each value separately, then it is a lot of work to concatenate and split the values each time. It really depends on how you plan on using the data.